# How to solve InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 mysql error?

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line-interface, innodb

> 2016-03-14 02:30:29 58150 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1,
>   error: 35 2016-03-14 02:30:29 58150 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do
>   not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or
>   log files.

Comment: Did you check for another mysqld process? It sounds like you're already running the daemon.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

First, list MySQL processes using the ps command:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

[image]

And then kill the process

```
sudo kill 56311
```

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, the solution is elsewhere. The problem stems from AppArmor misconfiguration apparently.

So just do:

```
$ apt install apparmor-profiles
```

and then restart MySQL (notice how fast it'll restart).

I noticed a file missing related to AppArmor when doing:

```
$ systemctl status mysql.service
```

Voila.

Comment: That solved the issue, just as a side note in case some one else is having the same problem; apparmor errors are reported on syslog at mysql startup. Errors look like this: audit: type=1400 audit(1490314801.743:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=21133 comm="apparmor_parser"

Answer (score 2):

It should say "There is another solution: the problem might be AppArmor".  If you do *not* see an entry in `/var/log/apport.log`, then probably AppArmor is not the problem.

An intriguing solution, however.

Comment: Great answer that clarifies the context of the other two answers. A suggestion, don't start with "I guess" you either *know* or don't post an answer LOL https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ... It might be good to link to another answer or some docs that support what you're saying but still, +1 for the answer as it stands, it helped me just now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue it was AppArmor misconfiguration
Data directory should be "rwk" whereas I configured it as "rw"