# Can't connect to mysql on localhost:3306?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

seems like a pretty basic question. but i can't find any duplicate answers.

can't connect to mysql.

I've reinstalled mysql-server. Doesn't make any difference.

MySql appears to be listening on a socket...

```
dara@laptop-20-04:~/Desktop$ netstat -an | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     690638   /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     690639   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

but i can't login as root

```
dara@laptop-20-04:~/Desktop$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
dara@laptop-20-04:~/Desktop$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[3] 119080
dara@laptop-20-04:~/Desktop$ mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111)
^G[2]-  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

my mysql.cnf

```
dara@laptop-20-04:.../mysql/conf.d$ cat mysql.cnf
[mysql]
bind-address = localhost

[client]
protocol = tcp
```

also tried changing `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

mysql version

```
dara@laptop-20-04:.../mysql/conf.d$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.21.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

help!

Comment: MySQL is listening on the Unix-domain socket `/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock`, not on the TCP socket 3306.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the log files were showing a lock file error. I should have provided this detail originally. You can check your log files for `ubuntu` at:

```
tail /var/log/mysql/error.log

> 2021-10-01T10:51:37.787720Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.21.04.3) starting as process 145495
2021-10-01T10:51:37.796108Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-10-01T10:51:37.820698Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
```

This was a misconfiguration of apparmor. I found a solution here...

[Stackoverflow mysql solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978228/how-to-solve-innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-mysql-error)

You first id all the mysql processes by:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
```

Then you kill all those processes. Where pid is the process id:

```
sudo kill <pid>
```

Then you fix app armor:

```
$ apt install apparmor-profiles
```

Then mysql starts no problems:

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, MySQL is listening only on the socket it seems and you force your client to use TCP.
Try the following:

```
mysql -u root -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: thanks. how come setting bind-address = 127.0.0.1 doesn't fix it though? I thought the IP address forced mysql to listen over TCP? Or am i mistaken?