# I'm running an API in a linux terminal and it crashes constantly. Log file error: [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11

Tags: python, mysql, linux, api

Below is the summary code of my API. I changed the parameters for privacy:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import mysql.connector
from functools import wraps
import numpy as np
import re

def query_db(query):
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return rows

db_config = {'host':'XXXXXX', 'database':'XXXXX', 'user':'XXXX', 'password':'XXXXXX'}

def get_db():
    return mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)

def close_db(conn):
    conn.close()

def with_db(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        conn = get_db()
        result = f(conn, *args, **kwargs)
        close_db(conn)
        return result
    return decorated    

app = Flask(__name__)

#Acessando a base de dados
con = mysql.connector.connect(host='XXXXXX', database='XXXXX', user='XXXXX', 
password='XXXXXXX', connect_timeout=60) 
cursor = con.cursor()

@app.route('/produtos/sem-repeticao', methods=['POST'])
def buscar_produtos_distinct():
    cursor = con.cursor()
    # Obtém o token do header da requisição
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    # Verifica se o header de autorização está correto
    if request.headers.get('Authorization') != 'XXXXXXXXXX':
        return jsonify({'status_code': 401}), 401
    data = request.get_json()
    nome = data.get('nome')
    # Validação de caracteres permitidos
    if not re.match(r'^[\w\s-]+$', nome):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Caracteres inválidos na entrada do usuário.'}), 400
    # Verificação de palavras proibidas
    palavras_proibidas = ['delete', 'drop', 'alter', 'create', 'insert', 'update']
    if any(p in nome.lower() for p in palavras_proibidas):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Palavra proibida na entrada do usuário.'}), 400
    query = "SELECT DISTINCT Info_Produtos, Foto_Produtos FROM produtos WHERE Info_Produtos LIKE %s"
    # Usa o método execute() do cursor para passar o nome como um parâmetro
    cursor.execute(query, ('%' + nome + '%',))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    produtos = []
    for row in result:
        produto = {
            'nome': row[0],
            'foto': row[1]
         }
         produtos.append(produto)
     return jsonify(produtos)

 app.run(port=5000,host='XXX.XXX.XX.XXX',debug=True)
```

The SQL error log file is below:

[image: Error Log]

What I've already tried:

1. Use the 'ps aux | grep mysql' and kill the most recent process, according this suggestion: [How to solve InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 mysql error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978228/how-to-solve-innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-mysql-error)